# How would I be able to know if the battery is still charging or full in Windows CE 6?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, windows-ce, power-management

When charging, how will I know if the battery is already full?

`GetSystemPowerStatusEx2()` only tells if it is charging.

Answer (score 2):

- [How to: Determine Battery Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms832321.aspx)

> The Windows CE [GetSystemPowerStatusEx2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453173.aspx) function can be called to return the [SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940385.aspx) structure. This structure contains important details about the power state of the device. Three of the most useful details in this structure are the **ACLineStatus**, **BatteryFlag**, and **BatteryLifePercent** members.
>
> To produce accurate and complete information, device manufacturers must populate this data from their battery drivers, as shown in the following code:

```
PSYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX2 pwrstat=0;
if (!GetSystemPowerStatusEx2(pwrstat,sizeof(pwrstat),FALSE))
{
    MessageBox(hWnd,_T("Couldn't get power state"), _T("Error"),MB_OK);
} 
else
{
    // Extract the power status information you need.
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to know if the battery is still charging or full when AC is plugged.

Comment: Doesn't `SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX2` provide exactly this information through the members `AC_LINE_ONLINE` and `BATTERY_FLAG_CHARGING`?